# Drupal 7: How to create a slideshow using Twitter Bootstrap Carousel?

Tags: 7, javascript

I'm a newbie when it comes to Drupal. But I know HTML/CSS, jQuery and Twitter Bootstrap quite well. I already have Bootstrap and jQuery installed and working fine.

I want to take advantage of Twitter Bootstrap responsive features and create a Twitter Bootstrap Carousel (photo slideshow) on the homepage. http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html#carousel

How can I set that up so that the photos and article links can be setup from Drupal 7 admin?

Comment: i dont know if there is any module to provide twitter bootstrap slideshow with Drupal, but what can you try is to create slideshow with  `views_slideshow` module and get all the styles from  twitter bootstrap, and style it by yourself etc. if you need more information, comment here, i will create a full answer

Comment: that's exactly what i want to do, to style it by myself. i already have twitter bootstrap and jquery working, all i need is the proper markup, and i do have the mark up, just don't know how to 1) add the slideshow to the homepage and 2) how to customize the markup. i think you have pointed me in the right direction, lemme try something...

Comment: are you trying to put image from article and you need a link to this article on your slideshow right?

Comment: yes, to look just like this but with different dimensions: http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html#carousel i'm almost there, but it seems i'm going to have to write several tpl files to remove a lot of the markup

Answer (score 2):

It's very late to answer this question, but I guess it will be helpful to any other like me who seeks for assistance in creating a carousel with the use of TB(Twitter Bootstrap).
Drupal community has come up with a module called [views_bootstrap](https://drupal.org/project/views_bootstrap) or [bootstrap_carousel](https://drupal.org/project/bootstrap_carousel)

which will help you create a responsive carousel powered by TB and Drupal.
The instructions given in the project page should almost give you what you want cheers!